# Only one observation but 2 points in ggplot2 qplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to visualize publication dates by academic discipline in a *ggplot2 qplot*.
`data$DISCIPLINE` is my factor containing 10 levels.

This is how my data looks like:

```
> head(cbind(data$DATE,data$DISCIPLINE))
     [,1]   [,2]                   
[1,] "2001" "Politikwissenschaften"
[2,] "2006" "Geographie"           
[3,] "1999" "Soziologie"           
[4,] "2013" "Architektur"          
[5,] "2007" "Soziologie"           
[6,] "2004" "Soziologie"
```

I produced the *qplot* as follows:

```
require(ggplot2)
MYPLOT <- qplot(data$DATE, data$DISCIPLINE)
MYPLOT + geom_point(aes(size=..count..), stat="bin") + scale_size(range=c(0, 15))
```

[image: plot]

Of course I want bins with 0 observations not to be plotted - this is why I set the range minimum to 0. At least, that worked.

---

However strangely, **single** observations received **two** points in the plot. See for example for the level *"Soziologie"*, **there are 2 points in the plot** in the early 80s, **despite there only being a single observations in my dataset**.

*Is this an error in ggplot2? 
How can I correct it?*

Comment: Can you share your data (or a sample of it)?  Is it fixed if you run `ggplot(data, aes(x=DATE, y=DISCIPLINE) + geom_point(aes(size=..count..), stat="bin") + scale_size(range=c(0, 15))`

Comment: head of my data added to my question. I tried your code, it does not fix the problem.

Comment: This is strange, can you show us a summarization of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
MYPLOT <- qplot(data$DATE, data$DISCIPLINE)
MYPLOT + geom_point() + stat_sum(aes(size = ..n..))
```

Comment: Thanks matt_k, that solved the problem! Although I had to add `geom_point(na.rm=T)` despite there being no NAs in my data. Don't ask me why.